# Cannot run Hello World Open

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am competing in the [HWO2014](https://helloworldopen.com/), yet I cannot run my bot. Here is the build file I was provided with, alongside the run file:

- **build:**

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  virtualenv env --no-site-packages --distribute

  source env/bin/activate
  ```
- **run:**

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  source env/bin/activate

  python main.py "$@"
  ```

However, when I run `./build` on the MinGW terminal, the following error is reported:

```
./build: line 3: virtualenv: command not found
./build: line 5: env/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

What does this error mean? How do I prevent it?

Comment: Do you have `virtualenv` installed on your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `virtualenv` on your machine. The run file is a bash script which is saying to go into the newly created virtual environment before running the python script. More info can be found on [the official virtualenv docs.](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)